# Comma to dot replacement not working in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

Here my problem:
I import data from a SQL database to another one. To do that, I need to use an excel macro.

When I import the data into Excel => numbers are separated with comma
Then, I replace the comma by dot using the following code:

```
Private Function FormatNb()
    With Application
        .DecimalSeparator = "."
        .ThousandsSeparator = " "
        .UseSystemSeparators = False
    End With    
End Function
```

It works well, I can see the change in my sheet :

[image: Result, decimal separator is a dot]

But, in the code, the change doesn't seem to be done 'inside' :

```
INSERT INTO TABLE VALUES('02/08/2022',2,24,2744808197021,2,89608192443848,75,2194137573242,0,100,024101257324,50,3323097229004,46,919059753418,54,2025413513184,54,3418502807617,54,6820297241211,31,1854991912842,53,7920608520508,35,7154998779297,58,4665489196777,64,6266403198242,9,31978130340576,63,1426811218262,49,9716606140137,0,693010807037354,13,7726097106934,600)
```

EDIT :
How I insert the data into the table:

```
    'INSERT for each row into the temp table

    Do Until i > lastrow
        cmd.CommandText = INSERTTable(windfarm, i, lastColumn)
        cmd.Execute
        i = i + 1
    Loop
```

How I create INSERTTable :

```
    Do Until col > lastColumn

        If col = 1 Or Len(sh.Cells(row, col).Value) = 23 Then
            sqlstring = sqlstring & "'" & sh.Cells(row, col).Value & "',"
            col = col + 1
        ElseIf sh.Cells(row, col).Value = "" Then
            sqlstring = sqlstring & "NULL,"
            col = col + 1
        Else
            sqlstring = sqlstring & sh.Cells(row, col).Value & ","
            col = col + 1
        End If
    Loop
    
    INSERTTempTable = Left(sqlstring, Len(sqlstring) - 1) & ")"
```

Do you know where does the problem come ? Any solution to solve it ?

PS : I also tried to change the parameters

Comment: Are you allowed to change the formatting of your data?

Comment: Exactly how are you generating the INSERT SQL?

Comment: The INSERT SQL in generated using a loop : I take the data row by row

Comment: I can do everything I want if it works ^^

Comment: Could you add the code you're using for creating the SQL - pretty sure the VBA code will always use a comma to separate numbers and dot as a decimal separator not matter what Excel is displaying on the worksheet.

Comment: I just add it to my post